# Sum of weakly convergent sequences defined on same probability space.

Tags: probability

Let random variables $X_n$ and $Y_n$ be defined on the same probability space. Let $X_n \Rightarrow X$ and $Y_n \Rightarrow Y$ as $n \to \infty$. Let $F_{X_n}$ and $F_{Y_n}$ denote the distribution functions of $X_n$ and $Y_n$ respectively. Does it follow that $F_{X_n} + F_{Y_n}$ is the distribution function of $X_n + Y_n$??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, $F_{X_n} + F_{Y_n}$ cannot be a distribution function as its limit at infinity is $2$, while it should be one for any distribution function.
In general, it is hard to express the distribution function of the sum of two random variable, especially if they are allowed to be dependent.

Comment: It is **impossible** to write down the distribution of the sum of two r.v.s with given distributions without further information. (Not just hard but impossible).